# How to change auto-format for Transact-SQL code in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: t-sql, formatting, visual-studio-2017, editor

How do I stop Visual Studion 2017 form auto-formatting my T-SQL code and changing the case of keywords, functions, etc? I want to keep the code exactly as I type it. The only relevant option I see is under **Editor - SQL Server Tools - IntelliSense - Casing for built-in functrion names**, which does not seem to do anything (I changed it to *Lower case*, restarted the IDE, but it still converts them to upper case). I did not find anything relevant under the **T-SQL90** and **U-SQL**, and I do not see any other T-SQL specific settings (I'd expect something like *Transact-SQL*, but there is no such option). Any idea?

Comment: Did you install Redgate Sql Prompt Core?

Comment: No, I did not. I'm just using VS 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the first place which can't be easily found without using the search bar. Also, it's not language specific either unfortunately.

[Search for 'format' and turn off 'format as you type' option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNtUg.png)
Here is the 2nd place I'm aware of

[Search for 'pretty' and turn off reformatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbhpn.png)
Hope this is helpful -- if you find a SQL specific way to avoid the annoyance please post a response to my answer.